# is this code safe? cast a std::vector<Derived*> to std::vector<Base*>

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Basically I've a `class A` and a `class B : public A`.

And I'd like to cast a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<A*>` to a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<B*>`

The problem is `std::vector<B>` doesn't inherit from `std::vector<A>`, and the `smart_ptr` neither. So I do a **horrible cast**:

```
  std::shared_ptr<VectorA> vector_a = * ((std::shared_ptr<VectorA>*)&vector_b);
```

The code compiles and runs there, but it is safe?
[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3dQTz1$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3dQTz1%240)

Comment: Short answer: No.  It's basically a reinterpret cast of the shared pointer, so who knows what it would do.

Comment: At least use `reinterpret_cast`, not C style cast here. And no, this is not defined by the standard (this doesn't mean it won't work, it's just not guaranteed).

Comment: Also, a vector of non-smart pointers is also just waiting to leak (and probably is).  use `vector<shared_ptr<A>>` or something, as then you won't leak (if needing polymorphic behavior) or just `vector<A>` if you don't.

Comment: @Kevin : true, sorry about that. I've simplified my code; I'm not using a std::vector but a custom template class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the dereferencing operations should succeed. Both vectors are pointer containers, so casting one to another, whilst unacceptable for production code, will still use the same dimensions and alignment.

C++ provides rich abstractions to avoid these shenanigans though, it would be better to populate the vector of derived objects as pointers to the base class.

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible solution. When you cast a vector of objects of one type to the other you can expect all kind of incorrect/undefined behaviour.

You should use vector of `std::shared_ptr<A>` from the beginning and initialize them with pointers to objects of type `B` there.

If it is not possible you can create a new vector holding `std::weak_ptr<A>` to avoid managing these objects twice.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that.

Consider that a vector of (pointers to) `B` is not a vector of (pointers to) `A`, or to be more precise, is not a universally valid substitution for a vector of (pointers to) `A`; thus, there is a good reason why you cannot perform such a conversion.

Although it is true that all you have in a vector of `B` is indeed a set of objects which are (also( instances of `A`, consider the following algorithm:

```
void f(vector<A>& v)
{
    A a;
    v.push_back(a);
}
```

Now imagine you invoke `f()` with a vector of `B`. That would be an attempt to add an instance of a class that is not `B` to a collection which is supposed to contain only elements of type `B`.

The solution here is to make the code which accepts only a `vector<A>` flexible enough to work also on a `vector<B>`. In other words, you need to make it a template. For instance, your template could accept as arguments only vectors of a type which is derived from `A`. This is quite easy to enforce with some SFINAE techniques and type traits such as `std::is_base_of`.

Answer (score 2):

You can still cast the elements:

```
A* a = vector_b->at (42);
```

gives you what you want.

Now, if you have written functions taking `shared_ptr<vector<A*>>` as arguments, then you have multiple solutions to take you out of this situation:

- use `shared_ptr<A*[]>` instead of `shared_ptr<vector<A*>>` (it works as you'd like to)
- take `A**` as arguments (and use `vector_b->data ()`) : it does not ties you to shared pointers.
- Better: take iterators which dereference as [smart] pointers to `A` (recall that `operator->` chains)
- use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` (wastes resources)